# How to installer MySQL Server to WIN 10 ? MySQL installer show upgrading not installer

Tags: mysql, windows-10

I have already installed the MySQL workbench before.

Now I want to install the MySQL Server to my local, I download the MySQL Installer 8.0.17 msi file in [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html) .

But open the msi file always show upgrading products , not adding products.

[image: MySQL Installer community]

[image: Show Upgrading]

How to adding MySQL Server to Windows 10 instead of upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a virtual machine to install your different MySQL version.

If you don't wish to go with a Virtual machine then you need to install wamp, xampp or winmnp package.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Where you see the upgrade and modify buttons there, on the top corner click on 'Add' button. Then select your products click on arrow and install.

[image]
[image]